# "Minecraft Properties" tab is not showing up on rig where the tab is supposed to be there

Tags: animation

I found a Minecraft rig for Steve on this video from YouTube as a Blender Minecraft tutorial for Minecraft animations.

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAOxANDjj5M)

The [rig download](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropboxusercontent.com%2Fu%2F53122678%2Fminecraft_rigV3.zip&redir_token=Uo03eSovzj9xdpLtaccpHwQ7h_V8MTQzNTYzMzA0MEAxNDM1NTQ2NjQw)

The video said and showed that this rig had a tab in the properties bar called "Minecraft Properties." However, this tab did not show up on the properties when I downloaded the rig.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a tutorial about using Blender, and not about using Blender itself.

Comment: @brasshat I do not understand why that is a valid reason for voting to close. The question is simply about why a panel is not appearing. Why would it matter that it's mentioned in a tutorial?

Comment: @RayMairlot, first, I reviewed the video referenced, and saw no reference to the "minecraft properties" panel; I don't know if I missed it, or if its in a different video in the series., or what. But I do know that the panel that the OP claims is not appearing, "Minecraft properties" is not part of the standard Blender distribution, nor a packaged add-on, nor a theme, at least not the I can find. Further, this seems quite similar to [question 33145](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33147/) in asking a question about a tutorial, for which there were several close votes when I saw it.

Comment: The panel is visible in the properties panel 40 seconds into the video. The user in the question you reference was having problems interpreting wording rather than having a problem with blender. I think the issue I have is the reason to close. The question isn't about a tutorial, it's about blender, it just happens to be mentioned in a tutorial. Whether this should be closed as 'too localised' is perhaps another issue.

Comment: Regarding the on-topicness of this question, I've posted a relevant meta [question here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/772/599).

Answer (score 1):

The 'Minecraft Properties' panel is not a panel that appears in Blender by default and will only appear when you have run a script to enable it. You will either need to write your own Python script to create it or obtain an existing 'IK/FK UI' script.

The tutorial maker doesn't seem to have included the script for the panel in the downloads they provide, but they do link to several tutorials in the video description on how to create your own UI such as [this one](https://vimeo.com/19661992) by CG Cookie.